# Tensorflow while_loop frames concatenation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, openai-gym

I have a problem to concatenate frames in a while_loop. 
First, a version that works but in a simple for loop. 
This version is pretty slow that's why I would like run this code in `tf.while_loop`

```
import gym
import tensorflow as tf 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

env = gym.make("Pong-v0")

def preprocess(frame):
    with tf.variable_scope('frame_process'):
        output_frame = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(frame)
        output_frame = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(output_frame, 35, 0, 160, 160)
        output_frame = tf.image.resize_images(output_frame,[80,80],method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
        return tf.squeeze(output_frame)

start_time = time.time()
frame = env.reset()
state = preprocess(frame)
stack = tf.stack(4 * [state], axis=2)
step_op = lambda action : env.step(action)[:3]

with tf.Session() as session:

    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(100):
        action = tf.py_func(lambda : env.action_space.sample(),[],[tf.int64])
        frame_, reward, done = tf.py_func(step_op,[action], [tf.uint8, tf.double, tf.bool])
        state_ = preprocess(frame_)
        stack = tf.concat([stack[:,:,1:], tf.expand_dims(session.run(state_),2)], axis=2)

    print("Done in --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    stack2 = session.run(stack)

    for x in range(4):
        plt.imshow(stack2[:,:,x], cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
```

> **Note** : In this version, I need to run `session.run(state_)` when i want
>   `tf.expand_dims` because if I didn't, I will receive an `Illegal Instruction!` and the images will be corrupted. I don't no why...

Here my second version with while_loop :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

env = gym.make("Pong-v0")

def preprocess(frame):
    with tf.variable_scope('frame_process'):
        output_frame = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(frame)
        output_frame = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(output_frame, 35, 0, 160, 160)
        output_frame = tf.image.resize_images(output_frame,[80,80],method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
        return tf.squeeze(output_frame)

def body(index,stack):
    action = tf.py_func(lambda : env.action_space.sample(),[],[tf.int64])
    frame_, reward, done = tf.py_func(step_op,[action], [tf.uint8, tf.double, tf.bool])
    state_ = preprocess(frame_)
    state_.set_shape((80,80))
    next_stack = tf.concat([stack[:,:,1:], tf.expand_dims(state_,2)], axis=2)
    return tf.add(index, 1), next_stack


start_time = time.time()

frame = env.reset()
state = preprocess(frame)
stack = tf.stack(4 * [state], axis=2)

i = tf.constant(0)
STEPS = tf.constant(100)

while_condition = lambda i, stack: tf.less(i, STEPS)
step_op = lambda action : env.step(action)[:3]
loop_result = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, (i, stack))

with tf.Session() as session:

    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    idx, s = session.run(loop_result)

    print("Done in --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


    for x in range(4):
        plt.imshow(s[:,:,x], cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
```

When I run this code I get an `Illegal Instruction!` and the image is not correct. I think it's because I cannot evaluate the `frame_` before expand it. Is it possible to evaluate my `frame_` before execute the `tf.expand_dims` in `tf.while_loop` like in my first example ?

Comment: Illegal instruction looks like you're using a tensorflow build which does not match your CPU's capabilities (avx, etc). Are you using a standard tensorflow?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I use tensorflow 1.8.0 with my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) and with a desktop I7-6700 (avx, avx2) + GTX 980. I run code with both of them and I get same result.

Comment: Can you try building tensorflow locally? Can you share more information, like a stack trace, about "illegal instruction"?